# Como verificar se uma string possui apenas letras maiúsculas?

Tags: php, string

Como posso verificar se todos os caracteres de uma `string` são letras maiúsculas?

De preferência, sem o uso de expressões regulares.

Comment: Por qual motivo gostaria de fazer isso? Não seria melhor ou restringir no input ou forçar letras maiúsculas?

Comment: Apenas letras maiúsculas? Números e espaços são permitidos?

Comment: @Begnini No caso especifico, apenas letras maiúsculas.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Para isso pode-se usar a função [ctype_upper](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ctype-upper.php).

```php
$string1 = 'ALLCAPS';
$string2 = 'NotAlLCAPS';

var_dump( ctype_upper( $string1 ), ctype_upper( $string2 ) );
//bool(true)
//bool(false)
```

Caso seja necessário permitir números, espaços e símbolos em geral, pode-se usar esta outra alternativa, que usa a função [mb_strtoupper](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-strtoupper.php):

```php
mb_strtoupper( $string1 ) === $string1;
```

Comment: mb_strtoupper apenas quando compilado com suporte a mbstring, 99% dos casos, mas vale ressaltar

Comment: @hernandes Exato, pode-se usar o strtoupper, mas aí caracteres especiais iriam causar problemas.

Answer (score 13):

```php
$string    = "ABCDE";  
$uppercase = preg_match('#^[A-Z]+$#', $string);
```

ou

```php
$string   = "ABCDE";
if (ctype_upper($string)) // retorna true se toda string estiver em maiúscula  
{  
    echo "A string $string está toda em maiúscula";  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Existe ainda uma outra maneira, que é comparar se a string é igual ela mesma na chamada de `strtoupper`.

```
$upper = 'TUDO UPPER';

$non_upper = 'Nem Tudo UPPER';


if (strtoupper($upper) === $upper) {
    echo "Sim, é tudo maiúscula";
}

if (strtoupper($non_upper) !== $non_upper) {
     echo "Não é tudo maiúscula";
}
```